# Node-sass is somewhere in a a dependency as it compiles and fails but I've replaced it with sass but it is still there?

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-sass

I've removed node-sass from 3 package.json files in the project I inherited. Replaced then with "sass"
However when I `npm install` I still get errors on the node-sass install.

```
pm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/xxx/Desktop/REPOS/MIT_WEBS/senseable.mit.edu/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh /var/folders/g4/lf8920h88xj5kn0059_t33x00000gv/T/postinstall-de171265.sh
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/Cellar/node/18.7.0/bin/node /Users/xxx/Desktop/REPOS/MIT_WEBS/senseable.mit.edu/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/18.7.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/xxx/Desktop/REPOS/MIT_WEBS/senseable.mit.edu/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.7.0 | darwin | x64
```

Is there way to see what package is calling on node-sass!

Comment: try removing node-gyp and node-sass from node-modules folder.

Comment: @TarunBisht sorry this didn't work since the install fails there aren't any folders in the Node_Modules folder...

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the package-lock.json file
2. npm cache clean --force
3. npm install

Comment: Check and check and check....sorry didn't work

Comment: downgrade npm / node to stable version!

Try:

Install 'n':   "npm i -g n"

Downgrade npm:  "sudo n stable"


"npm install"

Comment: NODE=v18.7.0 NPM=8.15.0